# Calculating maximum interval between different time at the same field MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, intervals, calculated-columns

I would to know if you can give me some ideas to calculate the maximum interval between different time at the same field.

```
id, npm, nama_mahasiswa, jurusan, fecha_hora
 1, CABRAL, 24, , 2017-08-25 15:27:12    
 2, RUSSO, 6, , 2017-08-25 15:32:10   
 3, CABRAL, 59, , 2017-08-25 15:34:15    
 4, RUSSO, 54, , 2017-08-25 15:38:21    
 5, CABRAL, 28, , 2017-08-25 15:38:47    
 6, FERNANDEZ, 61, , 2017-08-25 15:39:03    
 7, DUARTE, 56, , 2017-08-25 15:40:02    
 8, DUARTE, 47, , 2017-08-25 15:40:29    
 9, RUSSO, 69, , 2017-08-25 15:43:17    
10, CABRAL, 31, , 2017-08-25 15:43:35    
11, FERNANDEZ, 15, , 2017-08-25 15:48:14
```

Example, For each "CABRAL" I would like to know the different time for the first to second and second to third and third to fourth. Once i have this i would take max interval.

I would apreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, npm VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, jurusan INT NOT NULL
, fecha_hora DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1, 'CABRAL'   , 24, '2017-08-25 15:27:12'),
( 2, 'RUSSO'    ,  6, '2017-08-25 15:32:10'),
( 3, 'CABRAL'   , 59, '2017-08-25 15:34:15'),
( 4, 'RUSSO'    , 54, '2017-08-25 15:38:21'),
( 5, 'CABRAL'   , 28, '2017-08-25 15:38:47'),
( 6, 'FERNANDEZ', 61, '2017-08-25 15:39:03'),
( 7, 'DUARTE'   , 56, '2017-08-25 15:40:02'),
( 8, 'DUARTE'   , 47, '2017-08-25 15:40:29'),
( 9, 'RUSSO'    , 69, '2017-08-25 15:43:17'),
(10, 'CABRAL'   , 31, '2017-08-25 15:43:35'),
(11, 'FERNANDEZ', 15, '2017-08-25 15:48:14');

SELECT npm
     , MAX(diff) max_interval 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , TIMEDIFF(x.fecha_hora,MAX(y.fecha_hora)) diff 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.npm = x.npm 
          AND y.fecha_hora < x.fecha_hora 
        GROUP  
           BY x.npm
            , x.fecha_hora
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY npm;
+-----------+--------------+
| npm       | max_interval |
+-----------+--------------+
| CABRAL    | 00:07:03     |
| DUARTE    | 00:00:27     |
| FERNANDEZ | 00:09:11     |
| RUSSO     | 00:06:11     |
+-----------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: OP should consider use `LEFT JOIN` to handle those `npm` doesn't have pair to calculate interval yet.

Comment: It works for me but using MIN instead of MAX! With records that I posted here works with max but too many record by fecha_hora and when I tried to apply MAX doesnt work! THANK YOU!

Comment: @JonathanRojas OK, but that comment is rather absurd!

Comment: Sorry man! I was wrong! You´re right I was doing something bad. I applied two condition after: y.fecha_hora < x.fecha_hora where DATE_FORMAT(y.fecha_hora,"%H:%i:%s") between "17:00:00" and "20:00:00" AND date(y.fecha_hora) = '2017-08-28' AND date(x.fecha_hora) = '2017-08-28'. This way works perfectly!

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes, so your solution will inevitably slow things down. Of course, sometimes that's just unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with sub-queries.

```
SELECT `id`,
       `npm`,
       (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.`fecha_hora`, t2.`fecha_hora`) as `diff` 
        FROM table t2 
        ORDER BY `diff` DESC 
        LIMIT 1) as `max_interval` 
FROM table t1
```

I'm assuming your table name is 'table'.

The first parameter of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` defines whether to output the difference in seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

Comment: You need a connection between t1 and t2

Answer (score 0):

That might work, assuming you want to follow the IDs order:

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.fecha_hora, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.fecha_hora,B.fecha_hora) AS timediff 
FROM Table A 
INNER JOIN Table B 
   ON B.id = (A.id + 1) 
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Comment: ` B ON B.id = (A.id + 1)`   will connect the wrong rows

Comment: The assumption is patently false